# Getting local path to of the htdocs folder in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, path, zend-framework2

I was wondering if there is a way to get the local path in PHP using Zend framework. The application is located in the mamp's htdocs folder like this:

```
E:\MAMP\htdocs\frontend\public
```

I'd like to get this path, or at least the part of it in Zend?

Maybe something like

```
Application_Path/frontend/public/site/destinationFolder
```

Can someone help me out with this please :) ?

Thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use the php function `getcwd();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) for this (it returns the current working directory):

```
$rootPath = getcwd();
```

So public folder would be:

```
$publicPath = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public';
```

This works because [on line 6 of the `index.php` file of your ZF2 application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/index.php#L6) the working directory is set to this directory:

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

Comment: It returns the path to your application root, so where your ZF2 application is located. Maybe you should just try and see if it is what you need.

Comment: Okay I got the right path to the file but now its showing me this: Not allowed to load local resource:

Comment: @perkes456 You didn't write in your question what you are using this path for, so I cannot answer this. You asked how to get this path and my answer provides a solution for that. I'd suggest you accept my answer and ask a new question with all details about what you are using the path for.

Comment: Yes, that won't work. Your path points to an absolute path. So what your slider tries to do is load an image on the client from a folder with the following path `E:\MAMP\htdocs\frontend\public`. The browser is not allowed to read local sources on the client. If you want to load an image it is as simple as using a relative path: `src='img/image.png'`; (assuming the `img` folder is in `public` folder and `image.png` is a valid image in that folder, so here: `E:\MAMP\htdocs\frontend\public\img\image.png`). You should NOT use absolute paths for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112164/discussion-between-perkes456-and-wilt).